# Inconsistent behaviour for xs.sliding(n) if n is less than size?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

According to scaladoc, sliding() returns...
"An iterator producing iterable collections of size `size`, except the last and the only element will be truncated if there are fewer elements than `size`."

For me, intuitivelly, sliding(n) would return a sliding window of n elements ***if available***. With the current implementation, I need to perform an extra check to make sure I don't get a list of 1 or 2 elements.

```
scala> val xs = List(1, 2)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> xs.sliding(3).toList
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2))
```

I expected here an empty list instead. Why is sliding() implemented this way instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It [was a mistake](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/7939), but wasn't fixed as of 2.9.  Everyone occasionally makes design errors, and once one gets into the library it's a nontrivial task to remove it.

Workaround: add a filter.

```
xs.sliding(3).filter(_.size==3).toList
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be fixed sooner rather than later?

Comment: "Fixing" an API is always a tricky thing: by changing the behavior, you would break any existing code that relies on the partial windows being returned.

Answer (score 7):

You can "work around" this by using the `GroupedIterator#withPartial` modifier.

```
scala> val xs = List(1, 2)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> xs.iterator.sliding(3).withPartial(false).toList
res7: List[Seq[Int]] = List()
```

(I don't know why you need to say `xs.iterator` but `xs.sliding(3).withPartial(false)` does not work because you get an `Iterator` instead of a `GroupedIterator`.

Comment: `xs.sliding` is defined in the `IterableLike` trait, whereas `xs.iterator.sliding` is defined in the `Iterator` trait. The sliding method on IterableLike captures the collection type as `Repr` as a container for the groups. So if you call sliding on a List you get an iterator of Lists or on an Array an Iterator of Arrays. This notion of capturing the `Repr` type would need to be pushed down into the `GroupedIterator` to keep the same behaviour but also allow you to call the withPartial etc methods. Not sure what the pros and cons of this would be.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

Check [Rex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958712/inconsistent-behaviour-for-xs-slidingn-if-n-is-less-than-size/7959133#7959133) (which is the correct one). I'm leaving this just because (as Rex said on the comments) it was the original (wrong) idea behind that design decision.

---

I don't know why you would expect an empty list there, returning the full list seems like the best result, consider this example:

```
def slidingWindowsThing(windows : List[List[Int]]) { // do your thing
```

For this methods you probably want all these calls to work:

```
slidingWindowsThing((1 to 10).sliding(3))

slidingWindowsThing((1 to 3).sliding(3))

slidingWindowsThing((1 to 1).sliding(3))
```

This is why the method defaults to a list of size `list.length` instead of `Nil` (empty list).

Comment: This was the reasoning, but it's faulty reasoning: `slidingWindowsThing((1 to 0).sliding(3))` also probably should work, which means `slidingWindowThing` has to handle the empty case.  And if it can handle the empty case, it's fine for `sliding` to return an empty iterator (of type `Iterator[List[Int]]` in this case).  And then the length would be guaranteed.

Comment: Well I'm actually glad I had the same reasoning (though faulty) as the library designers at that time :)

Comment: @Rex Also... if returning `Nil`, how would you know that you've parsed every element? Some might slip because you're doing `sliding(3)` and the list actually had 2 remaining elements, right?

Comment: Indeed.  But if you are sliding them, you probably can't interpret only 2 out of 3.  After all, if you have a 4-element list and use sliding(3), the first and last element only are used once, while the inner ones are each used twice.  It's not instantly obvious what the right answer is...it's only obvious after lots of people use the library and start scratching their heads over unexpected behavior.